# Array out of bounds in for loop

Tags: arrays, for-loop, random

```
//dice throws to arrays
        int throws = 1;
        int[] oneDice = new int[throws];
        int[,] twoDice = new int[throws,throws];

        Console.WriteLine("Number of throws: ");
        throws = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Trows one dice "+throws+" times: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < throws; i++)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            oneDice[i] = random.Next(6);
            Console.WriteLine(oneDice[i]);

        }
```

It says my array oneDice is out of bounds, but i dont get why.. Please help me figuring it out.

Comment: You're creating the arrays with a length of one straight away. You should read the number of throws before you create the arrays.

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing wrong is to declare your arrays with 1 and after that you are changing your variable. changing variable will not change your array declaration so you will have to bear index out of bound error.

additionally, you need to put `random` variable declaration before `loop` so that you can get different result every time.

try this

```
Console.WriteLine("Number of throws: ");
        int throws = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] oneDice = new int[throws];
        int[,] twoDice = new int[throws, throws];
        Console.WriteLine("Trows one dice "+throws+" times: ");
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i<throws; i++)
        {
           // Random random = new Random();
        oneDice[i] = random.Next(6);
            Console.WriteLine(oneDice[i]);

        }
```

Comment: @Louise Bjerre Thomsen did you tried the code above?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It sure helped ^^

Answer (score -1):

```
        Console.WriteLine("Number of throws: ");
        int throws = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] oneDice = new int[throws];
        int[,] twoDice = new int[throws, throws];
        Console.WriteLine("Throws one dice " + throws + " times: ");
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < throws; i++)
        {
            oneDice[i] = random.Next(6);
            Console.WriteLine(oneDice[i]);
        }
```

The error was being caused by you defined the length of the arrays initially to one. Read the amount of throws first then create the arrays then there will be no problem.